# See AdMob earnings data on Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, admob, analytics

I am trying to figure out the way to see AdMob earnings data on Analytics. I would like to see, for example, the earnings produced by the New Users segment. I have already linked my AdMob and Firebase accounts but I still can't see how to generate this kind of reports.

Answer (score 0):

[As this google tutorial](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6360054), you can do it:

First, go to your AdMob account and on analyze tab, click on **Link to Firebase** on the app you want to connect, confirm the policy confirmation and select your project. You will be promted to [integrate the Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I have done that already but it is not enough. There is nowhere in Firebase anlytics where I can see this data.

Comment: Same here. AdMob section says it’s Linked correctly, but I don’t see any earnings. My project is an iOS app.